# Adding element to wicket component's html

Tags: html, dynamic, components, wicket

I want to add an element to my wicket component's html.

I want to achieve the following:

```
<textarea wicket:id="...">
...
</textarea>
```

result:

```
<textarea wicket:id="..">
   <div id="myspecialdiv">
   ....
   </div>
</textarea>
```

Does someone have an idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think you can add a div to a textarea but I may be wrong

Comment: Yeah, why are you adding a div to a text area? I don't think that's valid. Perhaps a different approach?

Comment: If you only want it to appear that the div is inside the textarea you could use CSS to reposition a div that is not nested... maybe some more info on your requirements/desired outcome would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange but possible you could use a WebMarkupContainer or perhaps a Border

- [WebMarkupContainer](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/WebMarkupContainer.html) it respect his inner content regardless if its valid or not
- [Border](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/border/Border.html) useful for decorate markups.

however your example is an invalid HTML, only God knows how that thing going to be rendered by the browsers

Comment: +1 for the invalid HTML. WebMarkupContainer is what you want.